# spring security escaping for username issue

Tags: java, encoding, spring-security, escaping

I have following code:

```
var shpa =  "<sprSec:authentication property="principal.username" />";
```

it renders to

```
var shpa = "mihailov&#45;ta&#43;spam33&#64;ya&#46;ru";
```

It is problem looks like escaping. it should be render like:

```
var shpa = "mihailov-ta+spam33@ya.ru";
```

How to encode it according my requirements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **htmlEscape**  attribute of **sprSec:authentication**. See [that](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/spring-security-part-v-security-tags/).
Example:
`<sprSec:authentication property="principal.username" htmlEscape=false />`

Comment: Make that: `<sprSec:authentication property="principal.username" htmlEscape="false" />`.